# CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExists missing in IDocumentClient but exists in the implementation of the interface

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the latest version of `Mucrosoft.Azure.DocumentDB(1.20.2)` and I can see that some of the methods that are in the `DocumentClient` class are missing in the interface. For example all of the methods related to Create..IfNotExists. Is that intentional and is there a workaround for using them from another interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tracked in https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/227

This is intentional in order to not break customers who implemented IDocumentClient before new methods were added. There is a discussion on the thread on adding new interfaces with version numbers.